# How to include a PHP file inside WordPress php template?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code I have inside `php` tags:

```
include('/wp-content/custom-php/numberedSteps.php');
```

And I get this error:

> Warning: include(/wp-content/custom-php/numberedSteps.php): failed to          open stream:
>
> No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/website.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/woocommerce/archive-product.php on line 85
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/wp-content/custom-php/numberedSteps.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in /home/user/public_html/website.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/woocommerce/archive-product.php on line 85

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try getting the root path first

for PHP >= 5.3.0 try

```
include(__DIR__.'/wp-content/custom-php/numberedSteps.php');
```

For PHP < 5.3.0 try

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-content/custom-php/numberedSteps.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       include (get_theme_root().'/template-name/file-name.php'); ?>
```

Regards